# ActionResult cast parameter base class to derived class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, casting, derived-class

I've written a base class and some classes which derive from it.

I want to use these classes in one ActionResult, but if I'm trying to cast PSBase to PS1 I'm getting a System.InvalidCastException that type PSBase can not be converted to PS1.

Classes:

```
public class PSBase
{
      public int stationId { get; set; }
      public string name { get; set; }
}

public class PS1 : PSBase
{
      public string reference { get; set; }
}

public class PS2 : PSBase
{
}
```

ActionResult:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProductionStep(PSBase ps)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var product = db.Product.FirstOrDefault(.........);

            switch (ps.stationId )
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        product.Reference = ((PS1)ps).reference;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

As I don't want to have for each class a own ActionResult (repeating much of the same code many times) I wanted put all this to one ActionResult. Any Ideas how I could implement this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm getting a error that this is not possible"? Is it a compile-time or a run-time error? If it's a run-time error, that means that `ps` really *isn't* a `PS1`.

Comment: I'm getting a System.InvalidCastException. Type PSBase can not be converted to PS1.

Comment: Then that is really what type the object is, and you won't be able cast it. I guess the issue you have is *why* the object isn't the type you expected it to be. The answer must lie in the code that passes it to `ProductionStep()`

Comment: The view I'm returning if ProductionStep/1 is called uses PS1 as model :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do will never work without custom ModelBinder (and even then it will be a huge mess I'd not recommend to implement), sorry.

Only when you are passing a model from Controller to View it remembers what type it was originally (including inheritance, etc.) because at that point you are still on the server side of the page and you are merely passing an object.

Once you enter a view and submit a form all that does it creates some POST request with body containing list of values based on input names.

In your case if you have a form based on PS1 and used all the fields as inputs, you would get something like:

```
POST:
stationId = some value
name = some value
reference = some value
```

(there is no mention of the original type, controller, method, etc.)

Now, what MVC does is that it checks what argument you are using in the header of the method (in your case ProductionStep(PSBase ps)).

Based on the argument it calls a model binder. What the default model binder does is that it creates new instance of that class (in your case PSBase) and goes via reflection through all the properties of that class and tries to get them from the POST body.

If there are some extra values in the POST body those are forgotten.

Unless you write a custom model binder for this default MVC implementation can't help you there.

I'd recommend creating two separate methods, one of each accepting different implementation of PSBase.

If you want to read more on Model Binders check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

EDIT:

By creating two separate methods I mean something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProductionStepA(PS1 ps)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProductionStepB(PS2 ps)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }
    return View();
}
```

then you have to distinguish between them in the view via different form action.

Comment: Thanks for this information. The way with 2 methods, is the way as I'm doing it at the moment. I thought the other way would be nicer :-)